# AudioKit in combination with an AVAudioSinkNode

Tags: ios, audiokit, avaudioengine

I'm trying to use an AVAudioSinkNode in combination with AudioKit. In the code below this is the flow: `Input > Fader > Output`. While the `SinkNode` gets attached to the `Fader`.

The SinkNode works but the audio further up the chain gets muted. I would expect to hear all input audio but instead there's no audio at all.

If I would remove the `attach` and `connect` from the `start` function the normal flow works fine (the input is send to the output). But obviously the sinkNode does not get any audio anymore.

How can I make sure the SinkNode gets its audio while keeping the rest of the flow intact?

```
let sinkNode: AVAudioSinkNode
let inputMonitoringNode: Fader

private init() {
    engine = AudioEngine()

    inputMonitoringNode = Fader(engine.input!)

    engine.output = inputMonitoringNode

    sinkNode = AVAudioSinkNode() { (timestamp, frames, audioBufferList) in
        // Store buffer to be processed in other thread
        // Not using a tap because it's to slow
    }
}

func start() {
    do {
        try engine.start()
    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }

    if (!engine.avEngine.attachedNodes.contains(sinkNode)) {
        engine.avEngine.attach(sinkNode)
        engine.avEngine.connect(inputMonitoringNode.avAudioNode, to: sinkNode, format: nil)
    }
}
```

I've tried attaching the SinkNode to other nodes but with no results. As mentioned in the comments I also tried using a `tap` but it's too slow for my needs.

Comment: If anyone has a suggestion for an alternative to the AVAudioSinkNode please let me know. It needs to be fast and with accurate timing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `engine.avEngine.connect(inputMonitoringNode.avAudioNode, to: sinkNode, format: nil)` I needed to use the connect function that accepts `AVAudioConnectionPoint`'s.

```
engine.avEngine.attach(sinkNode)

var connectionPoints = engine.outputConnectionPoints(for: inputMonitoringNode.avAudioNode, outputBus: 0)
connectionPoints.append(AVAudioConnectionPoint(node: sinkNode, bus: 0))

engine.avEngine.connect(inputMonitoringNode.avAudioNode, to: connectionPoints, fromBus: 0, format: nil)
```